# Group by related question. How to get the unique/distinct values, from a column that is not the grouped by column?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is the simplified query:

```
select column1, count(*), emails
from table1 group by column1;
```

however, the "emails" part would throw an error because the group by is for column1, not for the email column. What I would like is to get all the UNIQUE/DISTINCT emails, so the result of the query would be something like this:

| col1 | count | emails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | 4 | email1 email2 email3 |
| val2 | 10 | email4 email5 email6 email7 |
| val3 | 2 | email8 email9 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `listagg(distinct)`:

```
select column1, count(*),
       listagg(distinct email, ',') within group (order by email)
from table1
group by column1;
```

However, Oracle does not support `distinct` with `listagg()`.  One workaround is:

```
select column1, count(*),
       listagg(case when seqnum = 1 then email end, ',') within group (order by email) as emails
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1, email order by email) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
group by column1;
```